# In HTML5 Canvas and JS games, how might you check for collision between two objects when one's been rotated and the other hasn't?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I've been working on a game that's sort of a Worms clone. In it, the player  rotates a cannon with the up up and down keys (it's a 2D game) to fire at enemies coming from above. I use the `context.rotate()` and `context.translate()` methods when drawing the cannon, then immediately `context.restore()` back to the default canvas.The cannon is the only thing (for now) that's rotated.

The problem is, I want to accurately show projectiles coming from the top of the cannon. For this, I need to know the top of the cannon's coordinates at all times. Normally, this is something I could easily calculate. However, because the canvas is rotated only before the cannon is drawn, it's not as simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use simple trigonometry to track the top:

```
var canonTopX = pivotX + Math.cos(angleInRadians) * canonLength;
var canonTopY = pivotY + Math.sin(angleInRadians) * canonLength;
```

You can choose to render the canon using transformations of course, or share the math.

```
ctx.translate(pivotX, pivotY);
ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
//render canon from (0,0) pointing right (0°)
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);    // instead of save/restore

// calc canon top for projectiles here
```

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var canonLength = 70;
var angleInRadians = 0;
var angleStep = 0.03;
var pivotX = ctx.canvas.width>>1;
var pivotY = ctx.canvas.height>>1;

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#c00";

(function loop() {
  angleInRadians += angleStep;
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(pivotX, pivotY);
  ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
  ctx.fillRect(0, -5, canonLength, 10);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);    // instead of save/restore

  var canonTopX = pivotX + Math.cos(angleInRadians) * canonLength;
  var canonTopY = pivotY + Math.sin(angleInRadians) * canonLength;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canonTopX, canonTopY, 9, 0, 6.3);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot! Trigonometry was never my best subject and was a long time ago.